# Single quote within single quotes PHP

Tags: php, javascript, variables, quotes, html-escape-characters

I have a HTML achor tag like below:

```
echo '<a href="javascript:tempBuy('.$res_get_price[0][0].','.$res_get_price[0][1].','.$res_get_price[0][2].','.$dt_str.')">'.$res_get_price[0][0];
```

And the corresponding javascript function tempBuy() is

```
function tempBuy(rate,veg_name,market_name,dt)
{
      alert(dt);
}
```

But the problem is it does not alert at all ! May be I need to include the variable names within single quotes in `tempBuy()` function. I tried `tempBuy(\'var1'\,\'var2\'...)` but it shows error. How can I able to to that. Thanks .

Source for the part shows like this:

```
<td width="120px" class=""><a href="javascript:tempBuy(56.0,Apple,Bangalore,2013-05-18)">56.0</a>                                
                                 </td>
                                <script>
                                    function tempBuy(rate,veg_name,market_name,dt)
                                    {
                                        alert(rate);

                                    }
                                </script>
```

Comment: Did you check the generated JavaScript ? That would tell you if the quotes are right.

Comment: No. How can I check that? thnx

Comment: By looking at the source of your page. You'd see you're missing some quotes.

Comment: How does the rendered HTML look? (that should solve it). Also, what error does it show? Is it a PHP error or a Js error in the console? BTW, your `<a>` does not have the ending `</a>`.

Comment: you can check error in Mozilla tools->web developer->error console

Comment: I have edited the post. Please check

Comment: @Nitish - As you can see form the rendered output, you need to quote the last 3 arguments which are non-numeric. The correct output should be: `javascript:tempBuy(56.0,'Apple','Bangalore','2013-05-18')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't wrap your javascript arguments in quotes. You need to wrap each variable in single quotes, since you used double quotes for "href" attribute. Another thing is that you didn't close up "a" HTML tag.

```
echo '<a href="javascript:tempBuy(\''.$res_get_price[0][0].'\',\''.$res_get_price[0][1].'\',\''.$res_get_price[0][2].'\',\''.$dt_str.'\')">'.$res_get_price[0][0].'</a>';
```

Comment: Thanks Jack for the detailed structure. I am able to alert now :)

Answer (score 1):

If there is anything in your variables that is not a valid javascript literal you have to make it a string like:

```
echo '<a href="javascript:tempBuy(\''.$res_get_price[0][0].'\' ...
```

If there are ' in your variables you have to replace them with \' as well.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see form the rendered output, you need to quote the last 3 arguments which are non-numeric. The correct output should be: `javascript:tempBuy(56.0,'Apple','Bangalore','2013-05-18')`

The corrected PHP code is:

```
echo '<a href="javascript:tempBuy('.$res_get_price[0][0].',\''.$res_get_price[0]`[1].'\',\''.$res_get_price[0][2].'\',\''.$dt_str.'\')">'.$res_get_price[0][0].'</a>';`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript:tempBuy('".$res_get_price[0][0]."','".$res_get_price[0][1]."','".$res_get_price[0][2]."','".$dt_str."')\">".$res_get_price[0][0];
```